# Coderunner issues Mac

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-code-runner

Please can anyone help me out code runner only shows the right output after running the python file.

For example

Here I used the option "run python file" in terminal and it worked[image: Here I added used the option "run python file" in terminal and it worked]

Then i ran it using coderunner extension and it works[image: Then i ran it using coderunner extension and it works]

But when i change the output and run it, it doesn't change [image]

It only changes after i run it with python file. So I have to run it in terminal for the right output to show. code runner only mirrors the last output in terminal
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This may seem obvious but in the third picture, as you can see from the white circle on the tab where the x to close usually resides indicates that you have not saved the file hence it will output results from the last time you ran it using the 'run python file'. The 'run python file' button saves before running automatically so it would be easy to accidently miss the cause as now its saved with the new input and your code runner will output the new result again making it seem as though its duplicating the 'run python file' button.

Comment: Thank you so much I didn't realize this. Really helped me out